# Riemann sphere and Fundamental theorem of algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-sphere

Recently, I saw the following proof of the Fundamental theorem of algebra through the Gauss-Bonnet theorem. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0924.pdf
In here, $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ is identified to $\mathbb{S}^2$. Now, I have a question. $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$.
However, is it diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$? To use the Gauss bonnet theorem, $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ should be the smooth manifold. I have a trouble with the differentiability at $\infty$.

Comment: With the usual differentiable structure on the Riemann sphere, stereographic projection to the unit sphere is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I wanted the concrete description of that structure as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sphere $S^2=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ *becomes* a differentiable manifold once we've put a differentiable structure in it. We can do it with two charts:

1. The identity from $\mathbb{C}(\subset S^2)$ into $\mathbb C$;
2. The map $\varphi\colon(\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\})\cup\{\infty\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ defined by$$\varphi(z)=\begin{cases}\frac1z&\text{ if }z\neq\infty\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I checked that your charts are exact and $\mathbb{S}^2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\cup\{0\}$ by the one-point compactification through the stereographic mapping. Thank you so much!!